# Unable to obtain the response code! Pointers?

Tags: java, url, web-crawler, http-response-codes

I am trying to crawl 300,000 URLs. However, somewhere in the middle, the code hangs when trying to retrieve the response code from a URL. I am not sure what is going wrong since a connection is being established but the problem is occurring after that. I have modified the code setting the read time out and the request property as suggested.However, even now the code is unable to obtain the response code!
Any suggestions/pointers will be greatly appreciated. Also, is there any way to ping a website for a certain time period and if it's not responding just proceed to the next one?

Here is my modified code snippet:

```
URL url=null;

try
{
   Thread.sleep(8000);
}
catch (InterruptedException e1)
{
   e1.printStackTrace();
}

 try
{
   //urlToBeCrawled comes from the database
   url=new URL(urlToBeCrawled);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
 //The code is in a loop,so the use of continue.I apologize for putting code in the catch block.
  continue;
}
 HttpURLConnection huc=null;
 try
{
   huc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

}
catch (IOException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
 try
 {
    //Added the request property
   huc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
  huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

 }
 catch (ProtocolException e)
 {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

 huc.setConnectTimeout(1000);
 try
 {
    huc.connect();

  }
 catch (IOException e)
 {

    e.printStackTrace();
    continue;
  }

 int responseCode=0;
 try
 {
   //Sets the read timeout
   huc.setReadTimeout(15000);
   //Code hangs here for some URL which is random in each run
   responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();

  }
 catch (IOException e)  
{
   huc.disconnect();

   e.printStackTrace();
   continue;
}
if (responseCode!=200)
{
   huc.disconnect();
   continue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hanging because the response code was never received in the byte stream. You will want to look at an http debugger and see what was actually received, if anything at all. It did however appear to open the TCP connection to the server. It might not like your user-agent (which may not have been set to what you think it was) or the request method of `HEAD`, or it could be a server with limited bandwidth. You could use `Socket` class to just open a connection and ready the bytes in manually to see what you are/aren't recieving.

On a side note, using only `Socket` is not actually a bad approach **depending on what you want to do**. It *sounds* like you are writing an http server checker, in which case you will get more functionality out of using just `Socket` directly as you will be able to engineer better and much more optimized techniques (you are working with a large volume of low level network io after all).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the read and connect timeouts on the HttpURLConnection after you've called url.openConnection() which opens the connection.  Therefore they aren't taking effect.  I would probably use the [Jetty HttpClient](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+HTTP+Client) for this purpose rather than the Java URL class.

To answer your second point.  Yes, simply attempt to open a connection to port 80 (or other port if specified in the URL) at the remote domain name which you can extract from the URL (with `url.getHost()`) using raw Sockets.  For doing this i would use [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) rather than Java sockets.